# Display MySQL table ( number of rows are not same ) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have one MySQL table and it has two columns -

[image: table in database]

I want to display in my site like this -

[image]

I can easily take the table name `Boy | Girl` . But when i try to display the table I get like this -

[image]

I am just showing one example here. There may be 50 boys and 10 girls.. So I need help.

After displaying the heading

```
while($row_type = mysql_fetch_array($type))
{
    $type_name = $row_type['type_name'];   //Boy (or) Girl taking from another table
    $type_name = Database::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM details WHERE type='type_name'");
    echo "<tr>";
    while($row_name = mysql_fetch_array($type_name))
    {
        echo "<td>$row_name[type_name]</td>";    //Displaying the names
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

**So many views but not getting any answer. Please help guys. Please catch my mistake.**

Comment: show what have you tried!

Comment: better to show your queries.

Comment: You could pre-work the data, and put the boys and girls into a single string with `<br />` between them and then just echo out these variables. It's the ugly solution, but it works. :)

Comment: DEAR, try to paste your query first , means what you have tried till now

Comment: yes.. actually I deleted my codes.. that's why writing again. Sorry. Just a min

Comment: Is you problem to do with the creation of the table using PHP or is it related to the SQL query itself?

Comment: @user2605793 I am not getting you

Comment: This is a basic PHP loop. There must be a thousand examples out there. All the answers provided below (so far) are daft. Ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with two queries.
Make an array for each category(Male & Female)
It Works.

```
$maleQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE category='male'");
$femaleQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE category='female'");

while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($maleQuery))) {
$males[] = $row['name'];
}
while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($femaleQuery))) {
$females[] = $row['name'];
}

$number_of_rows = max(sizeof($males),sizeof($females));
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Male</td><td>Female</td></tr>";
for($i=0;$i<$number_of_rows;$i++)
{
 echo "<tr><td>".@$males[$i]."</td><td>".@$females[$i]."</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: great!! its working fine. But here **Male/ Female** are hard coded. If I want to make it generic, Then how can I do ? (Suppose I have **Male / Female / Eunuch / etc**)

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. Can you explain more about your table?

Comment: In this line you are writing **male** directly to get the list of male's available in the table
`$maleQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE category='male'");`  
But I want to make it generic. I don't want hard code.

Comment: So you have many such categories and you don't know the names of the categories. you want to write a query without mentioning category name. is it?

Comment: So You need to write another query. First get all the categories using a query. Then write single query inside a for loop.

Comment: $categoryQuery = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(category) FROM table");
while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($categoryQuery))) {
$categoryNames[] = $row['category'];
} --------


With this you will get all the categories into an array

Comment: Then use forloop.
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($categoryNames);$i++)
    {
    $query.$categoryNames[$i] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE category='".$categoryNames[$i]."'");
    }

Comment: I tried to get all the queries into a array even without knowing the category names see here.

<code>

    $categoryQuery = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(gender) FROM     gender_tbl"); 
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($categoryQuery)) 
     { 
      $categoryNames[] = $row['gender']; 
      }
//print_r($categoryNames);

    $arrayOfQueries = array();

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($categoryNames);$i++) 
    { 
 $arrayOfQueries[$i] =  "SELECT * FROM gender_tbl WHERE         category='".$categoryNames[$i]."'";  
    } 


</code>

Comment: thank you very much... Please update your answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Good to hear that. But my answer is not complete. I brought all the queries into an array and could not move further. You solved it yourself. No need to accept my answer. cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Try this query 100% working but set php code.

`SELECT IFNULL(c.Boy,'')AS Boy,IFNULL(c.Girl,'')AS Girl FROM 
(SELECT x.name,CASE WHEN (x.category = 'boy') THEN x.name END AS Boy,CASE WHEN (x.category = 'girl') THEN x.name END AS Girl FROM (SELECT * FROM tablename) X)c`

Comment: nice .. but here you are directly hard coding **Boy / Girl**. But I don't want hard codded code.

Comment: Ok.. That means there are category is not fixed.. right

Answer (score -1):

Is your problem to do with the creation of the table using PHP or is it related to the SQL query itself?

If it is the creation of the table then I suggest you use two tables embedded in a single table like this. That way you can build the first table using one SQL query, then build the second table using a second query, then display the table and girls and boys will appear side by side regardless of how many entries on each side. Your code would look a bit like this:

```
echo "<table>
      <tr>
      <td>
      <table>
      <tr><th>Boy</th></tr>";

$table = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM details WHERE Category = 'Boy'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($table))
    echo "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td>";

echo "</table>
      </td>
      <td>
      <table>
      <tr><th>Girl</th></tr>";

$table = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM details WHERE Category = 'Girl'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($table))
    echo "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td>";

echo "</table>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>";
```

If you need to cater for more categories, do an initial search to determine the distinct categories, then put the section of code above that creates the inner table in a loop.

eg. in pseudo code:

```
echo the outer table <table><tr>
SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM details 
while row1=get next category
    $cat = row1[0];
echo "<td>
      <table>
      <tr><th>".$cat."</th></tr>";

$table = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM details WHERE Category = '".$cat."'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($table))
    echo "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td>";
echo "</table>
      </td>

echo the </tr></table> to close the outer table
```

Comment: Suppose I have **10 categories** like `Boy / Girl / Woman / Old Man etc`. Then what I will do

Comment: In this case I have to write 20 table for 10 categories separately. The main thing is that I don't know the no. of categories. So I have to make it generic

Comment: To whoever downvoted my answer, could you please explain why. I am trying to help the guy with code that I use in a very similar situation. If I got it wrong at least explain why please rather than just downvoting me.  I have been barred from asking questions for a supposed bad reputation score so am trying to improve it by helping others.